# Facebook Graph api oauth exception code 1

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an app which uses *Facebook's api* to get conversations from my business page and user can reply to those messages. the app has been running fine since 2 years but today I receive an error:-

```
"error": {
    "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 1
}
```

I have read on a stack over flow question that this is because of a recent change in the Graph api and now page access token is required for getting conversations, but I'm already using page access token. I have tried it through graph api explorer and I'm getting the same error see screen shot.

[image]

EDIT : I'm getting this error only on the conversations edge, the send message function is still working fine

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/368515136975858/

Comment: Thanks for the link @CBroe this is exactly the problem i'm facing.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.